# Show What Functions Were Called In Javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging, stack-trace

I need this because I often work on existing projects, and I'm required to crash right into the middle of somebody else's work. With little time nowadays, I'm looking for whatever tool I can find to do this:

1. Load a JS application
2. Start / Pause recording activity
3. Show me exactly what happened, in the form of what functions were called without requiring me to change the source code.

For example:

```
<script language="javascript">
var fn1 = function(strvar){ alert('var='+strvar); fn2(strvar); }
var fn2 = function(strvar2){ alert('var='+strvar2); }
</script>
<a href="javascript:fn1(this.innerHTML);">click here</a>
```

After I click the anchor, (at best) should get something like this:

1. (click) event on a
2. (call) fn1("click here")
3. (call) fn2("click here") from inside fn1 called at pct. 2

Some sort of stack tracing but without having to alter the source because it takes formidable time as it is.

Comment: Have you tried Firebug plugin in Firefox? It has pretty nice support of debugging javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you write

```
debugger;
```

in your innermost function, you can open firebug or the chrome dev tools and their debugger will pause when it hits that line. Then in the section on the right of the tools, you can see the stack trace and other relevant data (locals, etc...).

You only need to add one line to a function you own and it will show you any calls made with anyone's code.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to find out, where to add that "debugger;" line, because I have handlers attached from external files, and tenths of scripts attached dynamically, along with the occasional var names in other language.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem now. You could inspect the element of interest. In the inspector (particularly in Chrome), the bottom of the right pane shows a list of event listeners and the functions attached to them. You could check that list and then add breakpoints where necessary (either by adding 'debugger' statements to your code, or manually setting a breakpoint in the debugger on other people's code).


Unfortunately, there's no great solution here.